# Use unique rows from data.frame to subset another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, subset, plyr

I have a data.frame `v` that I would like to use the unique rows from

```
#v
  DAY MONTH YEAR
1   1     1 2000
2   1     1 2000
3   2     2 2000
4   2     2 2000
5   2     3 2001
```

to subset a data.frame `w`.

```
# w
  DAY MONTH YEAR V1 V2 V3
1   1     1 2000  1  2  3
2   1     1 2000  3  2  1
3   2     2 2000  2  3  1
4   2     2 2001  1  2  3
5   3     4 2001  3  2  1
```

The result is data.frame `vw`. Where only the rows in 'w' that match the unique rows (e.g. `(DAY, MONTH, YEAR)`) in `v` are remaining.

```
# vw
  DAY MONTH YEAR V1 V2 V3
1   1     1 2000  1  2  3
2   2     2 2000  2  3  1
```

Right now I am using the code below, where I merge the `data.frames` and then use `ddply` to pick only the unqiue/ first instance of a row.  This work, but will become cumbersome if I have to include `V1=x$V1[1]`, etc for all of my variables in the `ddply` part of the code.  Is there a way to use the first instance of `(DAY, MONTH, YEAR)` and the rest of the columns on that row?

Or, is there another to approach the problem of using unique rows from one `data.frame` to subset another `data.frame`?

```
v <- structure(list(DAY = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), MONTH = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), YEAR = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L)), .Names = c("DAY", 
"MONTH", "YEAR"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))

w <- structure(list(DAY = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), MONTH = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 4L), YEAR = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L), V1 = c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), V2 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), V3 = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L)), .Names = c("DAY", "MONTH", "YEAR", "V1", "V2", "V3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

vw_example <- structure(list(DAY = 1:2, MONTH = 1:2, YEAR = c(2000L, 2000L), 
    V1 = 1:2, V2 = 2:3, V3 = c(3L, 1L)), .Names = c("DAY", "MONTH", 
"YEAR", "V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

wv_inter <- merge(v, w, by=c("DAY","MONTH","YEAR"))

vw <- ddply(www,.(DAY, MONTH, YEAR),function(x) data.frame(DAY=x$DAY[1],MONTH=x$MONTH[1],YEAR=x$YEAR[1], V1=x$V1[1], V2=x$V2[1], V3=x$V3[1]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, I would take `unique` of v first before merging. The `merge` command will by default merge on common column names, so `by` is unnecessary here.

```
vw <- merge(unique(v), w)
```

With your approach (take the first row from each combination), I think you could do (untested):

```
vw <- ddply(www,.(DAY, MONTH, YEAR),function(x) x[1,])
```

Comment: `+1` for a clean answer, but `ddply` is far from `base R`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Agreed; "base R" was intended to modify just the first line consisting of `unique` and `merge`. The following `ddply` line is an attempt to simplify the last line of OP's code in OP's original approach.

Comment: This approach works.  Just remove the final `)` in the second command. Does `function(x) x[1,]` translate as take the first unique row of x?

Comment: @nofunsally `function(x) x[1,]` is an anonymous function that does `[1,]` to `x`. Since `x` in your case is a data frame, `x[1,]` extracts the first row.

Answer (score 3):

```
 library(data.table)
 v <- data.table(v)
 w <- data.table(w)

 setkey(v)
 setkeyv(w, names(v))

 # if you want to capture ALL unique values of `v`, use: 
 w[unique(v, by=NULL)]

 # if you want only values that mutually exist in `v` and `w` use: 
 w[unique(v, by=NULL), nomatch=0L]
```

Comment: +1. Is `by=NULL` necessary in `unique.data.table`? The default is `by=key(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

Rather than merge a unique `v` with `w`, to get a unique `vw` first merge `v` and `w` and then select values unique on the `DAY MONTH YEAR` columns.

```
vw <- merge(v, w, by=c("DAY","MONTH","YEAR"))
vw <- vw[which( ! duplicated(vw[,c("DAY","MONTH","YEAR")]) ), ]
```

Comment: This approach results in a 3 row data.frame. 2 rows are duplicates in terms of "DAY","MONTH","YEAR"

Comment: Apologies. I misunderstood your request. This merges the unique values of `v` with `w`.  The approach `vw <- merge(v, w, by=c("DAY","MONTH","YEAR"))` followed by `vw <- vw[which( ! duplicated(vw[,c("DAY","MONTH","YEAR")]) ), ]` Returns the unique values of `vw` after merging `vw`. But this is all academic now!